# python logging - With JSON logs can I add an "extra" value to every single log?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging, structured-logging

I'm using the python [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module, along with [python-json-logger](https://github.com/madzak/python-json-logger) and I would like to add a few keys:

```
{
  "app_name": "myapp",
  "env": "prod"
}
```

To all of my logs automatically without doing the following.

```py
logger.info("Something happened", extra={"app_name": "myapp", "env": "prod"})
```

But for it to work as if I had. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `python-json-logger` and have a custom formatter class, you can add those fields directly in `log_record` in `add_fields()` method.

```
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import json


logger = logging.getLogger()

logHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
class CustomJsonFormatter(jsonlogger.JsonFormatter):
    def add_fields(self, log_record, record, message_dict):
        super(CustomJsonFormatter, self).add_fields(log_record, record, message_dict)
        if not log_record.get('datetime'):
            log_record['datetime'] = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
        if log_record.get('level'):
            log_record['level'] = log_record['level'].upper()
        else:
            log_record['level'] = record.levelname
        log_record['app_name']='myapp'
        log_record['env']='prod'

formatter = CustomJsonFormatter('%(datetime)s %(level)s %(message)s')

logHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(logHandler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.info("Something happened.")
```

This prints out:

```
{
 "datetime": "2021-12-28T23:43:25.503081Z", 
 "level": "INFO", 
 "message": "Something happened.", 
 "app_name": "myapp", 
 "env": "prod"
}
```

Comment: how about variables keys, can be use smt like **kwargs?

Answer (score 2):

I would just wrap the main logging class with the custom logic I needed like this:

```
import logging

class CustomLogger(object):
    def __init__(self, logger_name, log_format, extra=None):
        logging.basicConfig(format=log_format)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
        self.extra = extra

    def debug(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.debug(msg, *args, extra=self.extra, **kwargs)

    def info(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.info(msg, *args, extra=self.extra, **kwargs)

    def warning(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.warning(msg, *args, extra=self.extra, **kwargs)

    def error(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.error(msg, *args, extra=self.extra, **kwargs)
```

Then wherever you need a logger create it from that class:

```
from custom_logging import CustomLogger

logger_name = 'my_logger'       
log_format = '%(asctime)-15s %(app_name)-8s %(env)-8s %(message)s'
extras = {"app_name": "myapp", "env": "prod"}

logger = CustomLogger(logger_name, log_format, extras)
logger.info('Testing it out')
```

Hope this helps!