# change the keys' names in a python json logger

Tags: python, json, logging

I want to change the *keys' names* in my *python json logger*:

```py
import logging
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger

def main() -> None:

    logger = logging.getLogger("myLovelyLogger")
    logger.warning("something terrible happened")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    logger = logging.getLogger("myLovelyLogger")
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    formatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter(
        fmt="%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s",
        datefmt="%d/%m/%y[ %H:%M:%S ]",
        json_indent=4
    )

    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    main()
```

When I run it, *everything goes well*, I just want to change some keys' names:

```
$ python3 main.py
{
    "asctime": "29/06/22[ 13:44:55 ]", # <--- change "asctime" to "time"
    "name": "myLovelyLogger",
    "levelname": "WARNING",            # <--- change "levelname" to "level"
    "message": "something terrible happened"
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python logging - With JSON logs can I add an "extra" value to every single log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54471689/python-logging-with-json-logs-can-i-add-an-extra-value-to-every-single-log). There is also [example in the docs](https://github.com/madzak/python-json-logger#customizing-fields).

Comment: @buran the post you mentioned was indeed similar, but still different enough. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. I'll retract my closing vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently I missed [this option](https://github.com/madzak/python-json-logger/blob/master/src/pythonjsonlogger/jsonlogger.py#L93) in the documentation.

```py
    formatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter(
        fmt="%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s",
        rename_fields={"asctime": "time", "levelname": "level"}, # <--- added this line
        datefmt="%d/%m/%y[ %H:%M:%S ]",
        json_indent=4
    )
```

Then I get the desired result :

```
$ python3 main.py
{
    "time": "29/06/22[ 14:10:12 ]",
    "name": "myLovelyLogger",
    "level": "WARNING",
    "message": "something terrible happened"
}
```

Comment: Ahh, you were fast. I am just trying to add my solution. :D

Answer (score 0):

Renaming `exc_info` only works with version `2.0.6` or later. [See here.](https://github.com/madzak/python-json-logger/blob/5f85723f4693c7289724fdcda84cfc0b62da74d4/CHANGELOG.md?plain=1#L14)